# Where are my installed files on Amazon?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, django, mod-wsgi

This sounds like a real noob question but I cannot figure this out.

I'm trying to get Apache, mod_wsgi and Django playing together on my EC2 instance. So I've installed mod_wsgi using the root user and I'm trying to edit my httpd.conf as per the instructions [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).

So, my question is, where on earth is this httpd.conf file located on my Amazon instance after I ran `yum install mod_wsgi`.

Is there a command in linux that I can run that allows me to see all the directories and files installed for each user on the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf